lstlistings package: Replacing a character
I would like to copy/paste SQL queries from the PDF file while keeping the underscore character to be able to execute them on a terminal. I use sans-serif font for the listings since I cannot use monospace font so that the queries fit within the page margins. I have tried to replace the underscore from the \ttfamily using
\lst@ProcessOther {"5F}{\lst@ttfamily{_{}}{\texttt{\_}}}

without success. Furthermore, it breaks the coloring in \textsf{ROW\_NUMBER}.
\documentclass{article}

% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{mySQL}{%
  language=SQL,
  alsoletter={&},
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT}}
% To disable the replacement of hyphen with minus sign
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"5F}{\lst@ttfamily{_{}}{\texttt{\_}}}
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I would like to copy/paste SQL queries from the PDF file while keeping the underscore character to be able to execute them on a terminal. In the source file I have tried 
\begin{verbatim}
\lst@ProcessOther {"5F}{\lst@ttfamily{_{}}{\texttt{\_}}}
\end{verbatim}
without success. Furthermore, it breaks the coloring in \textsf{ROW\_NUMBER}.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL,deletekeywords={VALUE},{deletekeywords=[2]{TIME}}]
SELECT t, pt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNo, 
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS NoPoints
FROM RoutePoints;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


The problem with \_ is that in OT1 encoding it will not be copyable, you can replace it with \char 95 instead --- see my answer for more explanation. The text coloring issue I don't know.

@Esteban Zimanyi You should try T1 encoding instead of OT1:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

I added two things to your code:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  for copiable _ character.
alsoletter={\_} to prevent highlight of ROW_NUMBER.
\lst@ProcessOther {"5F}{\lst@ttfamily{_{}}{\texttt{\_}}} is not necessary.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for copiable _ character

% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{mySQL}{%
  language=SQL,
  alsoletter={&},
  alsoletter={\_}, % to prevent highlight of "ROW_NUMBER"
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT}}
% To disable the replacement of hyphen with minus sign
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
%  \lst@ProcessOther {"5F}{\lst@ttfamily{_{}}{\texttt{\_}}} % this is not necessary
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL,deletekeywords={VALUE},{deletekeywords=[2]{TIME}}]
SELECT t, pt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS RowNo, 
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS NoPoints
FROM RoutePoints;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


If you add ROW_NUMBER to the morekeywords list, then it will be highlighted also:


Alas, the publisher (Springer) does not allow to use raster fonts such as those used when using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

@Esteban Zimanyi - You are using Latin Modern fonts, which are not raster.

Thanks I didn't know.
